# Why I keep getting error after exactly 45 operations - LinkedIn URLs

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, linkedin-api

I wrote a code in python using selenium etc. to open LinkedIn urls to get logged in url. everything is working as it probably should, but I get error `Message: invalid session id` after exactly 45 urls imported into OUT.csv
Part of It is from chatgpt, but even AI couldn't help me with this one.
BTW. Im pretty new to python and its usage.
its about that I get links from sales navigator core in this format = "linkedin.com/in/ACwAAAJnuBoBdG...." But for further processing I need it to be in this format, which you get by manually opening the upper url while logged in "linkedin.com/in/jan-veleba" do you have any suggestion for automatization?

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import random

# Funkce pro získání aktualizované URL po 5 sekundách
def ziskat_aktualizovanou_url(driver, url):
    try:
        time.sleep(5)  # Počkejte 5 sekund
        aktualizovana_url = driver.current_url
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Chyba při získávání aktualizované URL pro {url}: {str(e)}")
        aktualizovana_url = None
    
    return aktualizovana_url

# Nastavte Chrome možnosti s vypnutou GPU
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Použijte správnou cestu k vašemu ChromeDriveru
driver_path = '/Users/martas02/Desktop/python/chromedriver'

# Inicializujte webdriver s použitím Chrome možností
def initialize_driver():
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Čítač pro sledování zpracovaných URL
url_counter = 0

# Pokusí se inicializovat driver a spustit hlavní část kódu
try_count = 0
MAX_RETRIES = 3
while try_count < MAX_RETRIES:
    try:
        # Initialize WebDriver
        driver = initialize_driver()

        # Přečtěte původní CSV soubor
        df = pd.read_csv('IN.csv', sep='\t')  # Předpokládáme, že CSV je odděleno tabulátorem sep='\t'

        # Určete index sloupce obsahující URL (předpokládáme, že je to čtvrtý sloupec)
        url_column_index = 3  # Použijte 3 místo 2

        # Zkontrolujte, zda je zadaný index sloupce platný
        if url_column_index < len(df.columns):
            # Vytvořte nový DataFrame pouze s URL zadaným sloupcem
            raw_df = pd.DataFrame({df.columns[url_column_index]: df.iloc[:, url_column_index]})

            # Uložte DataFrame pouze s URL do nového CSV souboru ('RAW.csv')
            raw_df.to_csv('RAW.csv', index=False)

            # Zpracujte URL z 'RAW.csv' a uložte skutečné URL do 'OUT.csv'
            out_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Skutecne_URL'])

            for i, url in enumerate(raw_df.iloc[:, 0]):
                try:
                    driver.get(url)
                    
                    # Upravte čekací dobu na základě indexu
                    wait_time = 20 if i == 0 else 40
                    
                    aktualizovana_url = ziskat_aktualizovanou_url(driver, url)
                    
                    if aktualizovana_url is not None:
                        out_df = pd.concat([out_df, pd.DataFrame({'Skutecne_URL': [aktualizovana_url]})], ignore_index=True)
                        random_time = random.randint(10,30)
                        # Zvětšte čítač po zpracování URL
                        url_counter += 1
                        time.sleep(random_time)

                        # Zkontrolujte, zda bylo zpracováno 900 URL
                        if url_counter == 100:
                            print("Zpracoval jsem prvních 100 a budu pokračovat opět za 24 hodin")
                            time.sleep(24 * 60 * 60)  # Pauza na 24 hodin
                            url_counter = 0  # Resetujte čítač
                            
                            # Uložte DataFrame se skutečnými URL do nového CSV souboru ('OUT.csv')
                            out_df.to_csv('OUT.csv', index=False)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Chyba při zpracování URL {url}: {str(e)}")

            # Uložte DataFrame se skutečnými URL do nového CSV souboru ('OUT.csv')
            out_df.to_csv('OUT.csv', index=False)

            # Přidejte získaná data do souboru 'IN.csv' ve sloupci 37
            df['SLoupec37'] = out_df['Skutecne_URL']
            df.to_csv('IN.csv', sep='\t', index=False)

            # Zavřete Chrome webdriver
            zavreni = input("Zavreni: Y/N")
            if zavreni.lower() == 'y':
                driver.quit()
            else:
                break  # Ukončí smyčku, pokud uživatel nechce zavřít prohlížeč
        else:
            print(f"Neplatný index sloupce: {url_column_index}")

        # If the script reaches this point without errors, break out of the retry loop
        break
    except WebDriverException as e:
        print(f"WebDriverException occurred: {str(e)}")
        try_count += 1
        if try_count == MAX_RETRIES:
            print("Max retries exceeded. Exiting.")
            break
        else:
            print("Retrying...")
            continue
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
        break
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do as it's a mix of Czech and English. As the URLs to LinkedIn below give a 404 error, could maybe add a screenshot and a link to one the URLs you're trying to capture? Or maybe even try to describe in plain English what you're trying to achieve? Then it's easier to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve with the access but look into the LinkedIn API here: https://developer.linkedin.com/ for help.

Comment: its about that I get links from sales navigator core in this format = "https://www.linkedin.com/in/ACwAAAJnuBoBdG...."
But for further processing I need it to be in this format, which you get by manually opening the upper url while logged in "https://www.linkedin.com/in/jan-veleba/"
do you have any suggestion for automatization?